# C programming - How to count number of repetition of letter in a word

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program where its supposed to count the occurrence of each characters using `getchar()`. For example if the input is `xxxyyyzzzz` the output should be `334` (x is repeated 3 times, y 3 and z 4times). If the input is `xxyxx` the output should be `212`.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
double nc ;
for (nc=0 ; getchar()!=EOF;++nc);
printf ("%.0f\n",nc);
return 0;
```

Input `aaabbbccc`, output `10`. The expected out put is `333`

Unfortunately , this shows the total number of characters including enter but not the  repetition.

Comment: On each new character, check if it's the same as the one you saw last. If  it is, increment counter. If it's not, print counter, then reset counter and set "last seen char" to this new one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply , Since i am a beginner I don't quite get what do you mean by check if its the same one as last. The command line is only able to take one word at one time.

Comment: What @SergioTulentsev said.  That means you need to save the character that `getchar()` returns, but remember it returns an `int`, not a `char`, and also save the last character that was read (so you can compare the new with the old, and then save the new as the old).  You get `10` because you counted the newline too.

Comment: I would also suggest "nc" should be defined as an "int" instead of a "double"... because its value will always be an integer, you will never have a "partial" character.

Comment: @holahola you want to search "*frequency array*", which is a simple scheme where you use an array initialized to all zero (with size of the number of possible object in your set, e.g. `26` if concerned with the frequency of lower-case character, e.g. `int charfreq[26] = {0};`) You then determine how to normalize your set so that the results corresponds to the indexes of the array (e.g. `somelowerchar - 'a'` would make `'a' - 'a' = 0;`, `'b' - 'a' = 1;`, etc.. Then as you loop over each char, `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) { if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') charfreq[c - 'a']++; }` The array is key.

Comment: a very good test word is 'mississippi

Answer (score 1):

you are missing two things, saving the last reviewed char and resetting the counter when updating it...

```
int c, prev = -1, count = 0;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
    /* if the current char is the same as the last one reviewed increment counter*/
    if (c == prev) {
        count++;
    }
    else {
        /* handle the start condition of prev */
        if (prev != -1) {
            printf("%d", count);
        }
        /* update the prev char reviewed */
        prev = c;
        /* reset the counter - upon char change */
        count = 1;
    }
}
/* print out count for final letter */
printf("%d", count);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is classically handled using a *frequency array* that is simply an array with the number of elements equal to the number of items you want to count the frequency of (e.g. `26` for all lowercase characters). The array is initialized to all zero. You then map each member of the set you want the frequency of to an array index. (for lowercase characters this is particularly easy since you can map `ch - 'a'` to map each character `a to z` to array index `0 - 25` (e.g. `'a' - 'a' = 0`, `'b' - 'a' = 1`, etc...

Then it is just a matter of looping over all characters on `stdin` checking if they are one in the set you want the frequency of (e.g. a lowercase character) and incrementing the array index that corresponds to that character. For example if you read all characters with `c = getchar();`, then you would test and increment as follows:

```
#define NLOWER 26   /* if you need a constant, define one */
...
    int c,                              /* var to hold each char */
        charfreq[NLOWER] = {0};         /* frequency array */
    ...
        if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z')       /* is it a lowercase char ? */
            charfreq[c - 'a']++;        /* update frequency array  */
```

When your are done reading characters, then the frequency of each character is captured in your frequency array (e.g. `charfreq[0]` holds the number of `'a'`, `charfreq[1]` holds the number of `'b'`, etc...)

Putting it altogether you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NLOWER 26   /* if you need a constant, define one */

int main (void) {

    int c,                              /* var to hold each char */
        charfreq[NLOWER] = {0},         /* frequency array */
        i;                              /* loop var i */

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF )     /* loop over each char */
        if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z')       /* is it a lowercase char ? */
            charfreq[c - 'a']++;        /* update frequency array  */

    /* output results */
    printf ("\ncharacter frequency is:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < NLOWER; i++)
        if (charfreq[i])
            printf (" %c : %2d\n", 'a' + i, charfreq[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "my dog has xxxyyyzzzz fleas" | ./bin/freqofcharstdin

character frequency is:
 a :  2
 d :  1
 e :  1
 f :  1
 g :  1
 h :  1
 l :  1
 m :  1
 o :  1
 s :  2
 x :  3
 y :  4
 z :  4
```

Look things over and let me know if you have questions. This is a fundamental frequency tracking scheme you will use over and over again in many different circumstances.

---

**Outputting All Frequencies Sequentially**

With changes to the `printf` only, you can output the frequencies as a string of integers instead of nicely formatted tabular output, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NLOWER 26   /* if you need a constant, define one */

int main (void) {

    int c,                              /* var to hold each char */
        charfreq[NLOWER] = {0},         /* frequency array */
        i;                              /* loop var i */

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF )     /* loop over each char */
        if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z')       /* is it a lowercase char ? */
            charfreq[c - 'a']++;        /* update frequency array  */

    /* output results */
    printf ("\ncharacter frequency is:\n");

    for (i = 0; i < NLOWER; i++)
        if (charfreq[i])
#ifdef SEQUENTIALOUT
            printf ("%d", charfreq[i]);
            putchar ('\n');
#else
            printf (" %c : %2d\n", 'a' + i, charfreq[i]);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

**Compile with `SEQUENTIALOUT` defined**

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=gnu11 -Ofast -DSEQUENTIALOUT \
  -o bin/freqofcharstdin freqofcharstdin.c
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "my dog has xxxyyyzzzz fleas" | ./bin/freqofcharstdin

character frequency is:
2111111112344
```

or for the exact string and output in question:

```
$ echo "xxxyyyzzzz" | ./bin/freqofcharstdin

character frequency is:
334
```

---

**Sequential Duplicate Characters**

If I misunderstood your question and you do not want the frequency of occurrence, but instead you want the *count of sequential duplicate characters*, then you can do something simple like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NLOWER 26   /* if you need a constant, define one */

int main (void) {

    int c,                              /* var to hold each char */
        prev = 0,                       /* var to hold previous char */
        count = 1;                      /* sequential count */

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {    /* loop over each char */
        if (prev) {                     /* does prev contain a char ? */
            if (prev == c)              /* same as last ? */
                count++;                /* imcrement count */
            else {                      /* chars differ */
                printf ("%d", count);   /* output count */
                count = 1;              /* reset count */
            }
        }
        prev = c;                       /* save c as prev */
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "xxyxx" | ./bin/sequentialduplicates
212

$ echo "xxxyyyzzzz" | ./bin/sequentialduplicates
334
```

Comment: Very nicely put answer, but you misinterpreted the question, ignoring all examples of expected output.

Comment: What do you mean? He has `xxxyyyzzzz` yielding `x is repeated 3 times, y 3 and z 4times` -- which is exactly what this does. If you want, e.g. `211111...344`, just change the `printf` to output sequential integers and remove the character identification. The concept is 100% the same.

Comment: I mean e. g. _If the input is xxyxx the output should be 212._

Comment: That is a *change the printf statement* issue and if I would have done that the learning aspect of the lesson would have been compromised.

Comment: I wonder how to _change the printf statement_ to make _212_ out of _4 1_.

Comment: See updated answer. The coding issue is determining *frequency*, how you want to output it is trivial.

Comment: I wonder why you refuse to feed the example input `xxyxx` to your program in order to see its output differ from the expected one.

Comment: No, I see what you are saying now, the `xxyxx` isn't intended to get the frequency but rather the sequential duplicate count. Updated again. More to learn here.